# How to find out why an ASP.NET web application is being restarted

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, application-restart

In my web application `Application.End` is called after every request for some reason and the application is restarted. When I set a breakpoint in `Applicaion_End` I don't get a useful stack trace. Furthermore, there are no entries in Event Viewer. According to MSDN, the following could cause an application restart:

> - Adding, modifying, or deleting assemblies from the application's Bin
>     folder.
> - Adding, modifying, or deleting localization resources from the
>     App_GlobalResources or App_LocalResources folders.
> - Adding, modifying, or deleting the application's Global.asax file.
> - Adding, modifying, or deleting source code files in the App_Code
>     directory.
> - Adding, modifying, or deleting Profile configuration.
> - Adding, modifying, or deleting Web service references in the
>     App_WebReferences directory.
> - Adding, modifying, or deleting the application's Web.config file.

I guess that my code changes some file which triggers an application restart. Is there any way to find out what exactly causes the application restarts?

**Edit:** I solved my problem now by stepping through the code and watching the timestamps in Explorer. On application startup I'm reading a value from an access database which causes a .ldb file to be created and deleted. However, this question has not been answered yet. Is there any log that keeps record of such events that cause the application to be restarted?

Comment: are you working on iis ? maybe it's a restart caused by app pool recycle.

Comment: Why dont you just sort the files and folders by modification date?

Comment: @BigMike Yes, I'm on IIS. I enabled all log entries for app pool recycling but there are no entries in Event Viewer, so I think it's just an application restart. Also, the same thing happens in Visual Studio Development Server.

Comment: @MihalisBagos Thanks :) for some reason the time stamp of the `bin` folder is updated on every request, however none of the files in there has its time stamp updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tess Ferrandez wrote a good [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx) on how to determine the reason for App Domain recycling. Tess has this to say on how to log the restart event:

> How do you determine what caused an appdomain restart?   In ASP.NET
>   2.0 you can use the built in Health Monitoring Events to log application restarts along with the reason for the restart.  To do
>   this you change the master web.config file in the
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG directory and add
>   the following section

```
<healthMonitoring>
  <rules>
    <add name="Application Lifetime Events Default" 
         eventName="Application Lifetime Events"
         provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Default" minInstances="1"
         maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" custom="" />
```

To turn on logging for IIS6 you can use:

```
cscript adsutil.vbs Set w3svc/AppPools/DefaultAppPool/LogEventOnRecycle 255
```

For IIS7 you can control it from the IIS manager - Application pools - Advanced Settings.

Comment: I do not believe that the App Pool - Advanced Settings you are referring to are the same thing as Health Monitoring.  Those settings are specific to Recycling events.  They do not cover the full gamut of the default health monitoring events configured in the eventMappings element of healthMonitoring.    As far as I can tell, you should still use the machine-level web.config's healthMonitoring settings for all versions of .NET and IIS.  They are more granular and you can also setup different providers, such as an email provider, event log provider, or SQL provider to capture the health event.