# How often ASP.NET typically recycles its applications (AppDomains)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I initialize static state of my web applications in Applications_Start method (Global.asax). At that time I write a message to log. Suddenly I've realized that this method was called every 10 minutes.

Is it corrected behavior? I expected ASP.NET to keep its applications at least for several hours.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is incorrect. This is set in the application pool setting in IIS configuration. I think the default is 20 minutes. This can be changed to 0 if the application pool should not be recycled.

Comment: maybe after inactivity this is correct, but I think it is much longer if the site is getting hit.

Comment: 29 hours is the default.  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/periodicrestart

Comment: We're talking about two different things. I meant the inactivity recycle time not forced pool recycle after a fixed amount of time.

Comment: OK, I got it. But my site was not inactive :)

Comment: Is it deployed on shared hosting or is it on vps or your server?

Answer (score 0):

This is not typical.  Something is causing it to restart and it should not be doing so this frequently.  Check out [How to find out why an ASP.NET web application is being restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678024/how-to-find-out-why-an-asp-net-web-application-is-being-restarted) question to see how you can log details on why it restarted.

Since you are writing out log files, maybe you are writing them to a location that is be monitored for recompilation, which will cause a appdomain restart.  Check out the post [What causes an application pool in IIS to recycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/what-causes-an-application-pool-in-iis-to-recycle)

Check out this article on [iis.net](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/periodicrestart) to see the default for recycleing.  It is 29 hours, so unless this setting has been changed for you, something else is causing it, not the automatic recycle.