# ASP.NET Session Keeps Expiring

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis, windows-authentication

I have this web application that servers over 300 employees which uses Windows Authentication. The session is set on web.config as:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <sessionState timeout="60"/>
```

While the session should expire in 60 minutes. Some users are being asked for their Windows Login credentials randomly. Some even less than 10 minutes.

Based on a tip from a friend, I increased the Idle time of the Application Pool process to 60 min also.

Still, some users are being asked for their Windows Login again.

Is there anything I should do on IIS? or is it ASP.NET related? or Windows Authentication related?

MORE:
I have developed other applications with similar code. But they are serving less than 50 people. This one is serving over 300. Those applications are working fine and users never been asked to provide their passwords again. Only this huge application is doing that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you inspect the eventlog on the webserver do you see restarts of the appdomain?

Comment: I can check that. but what to look for exactly in the event log? is there any code for the restart event?

Comment: It needs to be configured first: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678024/how-to-find-out-why-an-asp-net-web-application-is-being-restarted)

Comment: go through this link http://wiki.productcart.com/developers/timeout-issues